# JComponent does not appear in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jcomponent, preferredsize

I've successfully built a JComponent pie chart which resides in it's own separate class IAPieChart.java. The PieChart logic is in a static inner class that extends JComponent. The JApplet itself builds fine and displays 'here I am!' to indicate that the panels were built and added using this code:

```
public class IAPieChartApplet extends JApplet {

     JPanel controls;
     JPanel chartPanel;
     JComponent pieChart;

    /**
     * Initialization method that will be called after the Applet is loaded into
     * the browser.
     */

    public void init() {

        // Build the Pie Chart Panel
        buildPieChartPanel();

        // Build the controls panel
        buildControlsPanel();

        //Set the Layout
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //getContentPane().add(new PieChart(), controls);
        //add(chartPanel);
        //add(controls);

    }



    private void buildPieChartPanel(){

        // Build the panel JPanel
        chartPanel = new JPanel();
        pieChart = new PieChart();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Here I Am!");
        chartPanel.add(pieChart);
        chartPanel.add(label);

    }

    private void buildControlsPanel() {

        controls = new JPanel();
        JLabel here = new JLabel("Here I Am");
        controls.add(here);

    }

}
```

When I run this IAPieChartApplet.java file, I get the labels and no PieChart.

[image: Lables and No PieChart]

I set a method breakpoint here and step into the static PieChart class:

```
private void buildPieChartPanel(){

        // Build the panel JPanel
        chartPanel = new JPanel();
        pieChart = new PieChart();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Here I Am!");
        chartPanel.add(pieChart);
        chartPanel.add(label);

    }
```

Debug takes me as far as here, then steps back out out of the class. It does step through the rest of the logic in the PieChart class. This is the code to the PieChart static class, which again, runs fine. Debug will take me as far as the IAPieChart array then step back out of the method. And this is 'probably' why it's not displaying.

[image]

This is the PieChart Class code:

```
public static class PieChart extends JComponent { 

        IAPieChart[] pieValue = {new IAPieChart(2, Color.green),
                                new IAPieChart(4, Color.orange),
                                new IAPieChart(4, Color.blue),
                                new IAPieChart(3, Color.red)

        };

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            drawPie((Graphics2D) g, getBounds(),  pieValue);

        }

        void drawPie(Graphics2D g, Rectangle area, IAPieChart[] pieValue){

            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pieValue.length; i++) {

                sum += pieValue[i].arcValue;
            }
            // DONT NEED endPoint to make the pieChart (Mishadoff's sample). 
            // needs double endPoint = 0.0D for (phcoding's sample).
            double endPoint =  0.0D;
            int arcStart = 0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < pieValue.length; i++){

                /////////THIS IS THE OLD STATEMENT////////
                //endPoint += (int) (endPoint * 360 / sum);
                arcStart = (int) (endPoint * 360 / sum);

                // this statement makes the pieChart.
                int radius = (int) (pieValue[i].arcValue * 360/ sum);
                g.setColor(pieValue[i].color);
                //g.fillArc(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height, arcStart , radius);
                g.fillArc(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height, arcStart , radius);

                ///////THIS IS THE OLD STATEMENT////
                //arcStart += pieValue[i].arcValue;
                endPoint += pieValue[i].arcValue;

                // this statement will make the pieChart.
                //arcStart += radius;
            }

        }
    }   // END PieChart class.*
```

I've tried using getContentPane(), repaint(), and whatever else looked good in my searches, and I'm just out of options. I've been doing well over the last several weeks but this assignment has been stumping me left and right. I'm hoping you can help.

Comment: `setEnabled()`? `setVisible()`?

Comment: ValekHalfHeart: I did try because you took the time to post however, they didn't work. I honeslty believe that this is happening because the static PieChart class isn't being read all the way through. Debug says that the array is loaded, it's just not rendering <-- for lack of the proper word, in the Applet. This is why I tried repaint(); I have about 9-10 weeks experience so I am trying to use all the resources I"ve accumulated during this time, unfortunatly to no avail. 

Thank your for your interest and help.

Comment: `The PieChart logic is in a static inner class that extends JComponent` - It should not be a static inner class. It should be a public class that you create directly. Then once you fix that you need to override the getPreferredSize() method to return a value so your FlowLayout can do its job.

Answer (score 2):

The pie chart does not appear as `PieChart` does not have any preferred size. Therefore the containing `JPanel` which uses the default `FlowLayout` does not display it. `getPreferredSize` should be used over `setPreferredSize`:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
   return new Dimension(100, 100);
}
```

*Update:*

In your revised applet, you are extending the old AWT `Applet` which does not override `paintComponent`, use `JApplet` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have redone the program to the best of my ability, using the recommendations given, and the graphic still will not show in the applet. After getting rid of the instantiation error I got the applet to build successfully however the pie chart will not show up. I am hoping someone will help wiht this so that I can move on to other features with this program.

Here is what I have now:

```
package iapiechart;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class IAPieChart2 extends Applet
{
   double arcValue;        // passes a value for the calculation of the arc.
    Color color;            // holds value for color (expressed as an integer
    public IAPieChart2(){};
    public IAPieChart2(double value, Color color){

        arcValue = value;
        this.color = color;
    } 

    public  class PieChart extends JComponent { 

        public PieChart(){};

        IAPieChart[] pieValue = {new IAPieChart(2, Color.green),
                                new IAPieChart(4, Color.orange),
                                new IAPieChart(4, Color.blue),
                                new IAPieChart(3, Color.red)

        };
        @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            drawPie((Graphics2D) g, getBounds(),  pieValue);

        }
    void drawPie(Graphics2D g, Rectangle area, IAPieChart[] pieValue){

            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pieValue.length; i++) {

                sum += pieValue[i].arcValue;
            }
            // DONT NEED endPoint to make the pieChart (Mishadoff's sample). 
            // needs double endPoint = 0.0D for (phcoding's sample).
            double endPoint =  0.0D;
            int arcStart = 0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < pieValue.length; i++){

                /////////THIS IS THE OLD STATEMENT////////
                //endPoint += (int) (endPoint * 360 / sum);
                arcStart = (int) (endPoint * 360 / sum);

                // this statement makes the pieChart.
                int radius = (int) (pieValue[i].arcValue * 360/ sum);
                g.setColor(pieValue[i].color);
                //g.fillArc(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height, arcStart , radius);
                g.fillArc(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height, arcStart , radius);

                endPoint += pieValue[i].arcValue;

            }
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void init(){

        IAPieChart2 iap2 = new IAPieChart2();
        PieChart pc = new PieChart();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        iap2.getPreferredSize();
        super.add(pc);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```